# a transformation which takes a $xz$ plane to a plane parallel to it

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ which takes an $XZ$ plane (i.e $X=0$) to a plane parallel to it (i.e $X=1$).

I thought along these lines:

Let $T$ be such a linear transformation. Then I assigned $T(0,0,1)=(1,0,1)$, $T(0,1,0)=(1,1,0)$,$T(1,0,0)=(1,0,-1)$

But the problem with it is that for any linear combination of $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$, the transformation should yield something like $(1,y_1,z_1)$.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *linear* map like this. What you want is an *affine* map. Many people say "linear" when they mean "affine," but it can get confusing when the difference is important.

**Definitions**

Linear maps preserve scalar multiplication and vector addition. $L$ is linear if $$L(x+u,y+v,z+w)=L(x,y,z)+L(u,v,w)$$
and
$$L(ax,ay,az)=aL(x,y,z).$$

An affine map is linear plus a constant. $T$ is affine if $$T(x,y,z)=L(x,y,z)+v$$ where $L$ is some linear map and $v$ is a constant vector.

I would normally call the plane where $x=0$ the $YZ$- rather than $XZ$-plane.

**An Affine Solution**

Let $T(x,y,z)=(1,y,z)$. In matrix form, $$T(x,y,z)=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It is very easy to show that $T$ is affine, and the plane where $x=0$ (and in fact all of $\mathbb{R}^3$) is mapped to the plane where $x=1$.

**There is no such linear map**

You can easily prove there is no such linear map: suppose $T$ is linear and there are two points in the $YZ$-plane--call them $(0,y_1,z_1)$ and $(0,y_2,z_2)$--that get mapped to the $x=1$ plane--let's say $T(0,y_1,z_1)=(1,u_1,v_1)$ and $T(0,y_2,z_2)=(1,u_2,v_2)$. Then $$\begin{align}T(0,y_1+y_2,z_1+z_2)
=&T(0,y_1,z_1)+T(0,y_2,z_2)\\
=&(1,u_1,v_1)+(1,u_2,v_2)\\
=&(2,u_1+u_2,v_1+v_2)
\end{align}$$
which is not in the $x=1$ plane. So the entire $YZ$-plane does not get mapped to the $x=1$ plane by any linear map.